# Infinite additional pages being created in a subdirectory

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to get to the bottom of an issue Moz's crawler got stuck on. The easy problem we need to fix is that we have duplicates of the same page i.e.:

```
/capabilities/  
/capabilities/index.html
```

That problem is occurring for a handful or directories. But we also have an issue that seems to be making an infinite loop of pages that can be accessed, just for this subdirectory:

```
/customer_service.html/  
/customer_service.html/contact/index.html  
/customer_service.html/contact_us/contact_form.php  
/customer_service.html/contact/contact/contact/contact/index.html
/customer_service.html/contact/contact/contact_us/contact_form.php
/customer_service.html/contact_us/contact/contact/contact/index.html
/customer_service.html/contact_us/contact/contact/contact_us/contact_form.php
/customer_service.html/contact/contact_us/contact/contact_us/contact_us/contact/index.html
```

And on and on and on... I think it stopped crawling just because it reached 24,000 pages. All these pages actually work. Really there only need to be two pages: one for customer service FAQs, and one for contacting the company.

I'm a marketer, not a developer, so all I know is that this is an issue. I'm wondering whether we can fix this using htaccess, or if there is another problem. It seems to me like all these other pages need to be eliminated, not just redirected. Thanks.

edit: added more examples for illustrative and comic purposes

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to do.

One is, like you say, not to allow these URLs to redirect to the main page. Show what you have in your .htaccess file, I will look how you could change it.

On the other hand, it is not sufficient to address the symptom. You have to heal the sickness. Here it means that you have some incorrect links on your site. Most probably these are relative URLs that are missing the initial slash ( contact instead of /contact ).

Comment: We modified at least one internal link and that seemed to be enough for Moz's crawler to stop sounding the alarm for duplicate content... but those crazy URLs still work. Good enough?

Comment: I'd change .htaccess in a way that makes those links invalid.